# how to find if a certain bucket/folder is configured for multi part file upload

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to complete a multi-part upload to S3 but getting failed with 403 **AccessDenied**. How to find if a certain bucket/folder is configured for multi part file upload as part of the AWS policy.

> {"code" : 500,
>   "message" : "Error initiating MultipartUploadResult: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 3215EEC708AC0XXC; S3 Extended Request ID: eF5EBmDp6Pqribb+FGOd7rEBB42lPdVPdOxamp3nda7nsACI07VwQ7SOOowxXfSCV3eG332ahuY=)"}

Comment: Buckets do not need to be enabled for multi-part uploads. The issue would be related to permissions, either on the bucket or on your IAM User. What are the S3 permissions associated with the credentials you are using?

Comment: We are using EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper to get AWS credentials.

Comment: Did you assign an IAM Role to the task definition? If so, the credentials will be passed to the task via the Amazon EC2 Instance Metadata Service. See: [IAM Roles for Tasks - Amazon Elastic Container Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a multipart upload if you have the write access to that specific bucket. Kindly check if the role you are using is having write permissions to S3. For testing, you can attach the AmazonS3FullAccess policy to your role, you should be able to do the upload now.

By the way, all you need to have PutObject permission to do a multipart upload. There is no specific configuration for enabling/disabling it. Here is a doc for further reference.

> `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuAndPermissions.html`